# Typo in Stanley, Enumerative combinatorics II, Cor. 7.23.9?

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, symmetric-functions

In Stanley, EC2, we have the following statement:

[image: screenshot from corollary 7.23.9]

I think there is a typo in the first sum after "generating function",
and that $[n]_q!$ should be replaced by $(1-q)(1-q^2)\dotsb (1-q^n)$,
and same for $[n]_t!$.

The problem with the proof seems to be the line

[image: line of proof]

which is incorrect(?) as the denominator on the right hand side should be
not the q/t-factorials, but the above product, according to the lemma which is referenced there.

This issue (if my suspicions hold), is not listed in the [Errata.](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/ec2supp.pdf).

I have also checked this in Mathematica, so I am fairly confident this is a typo.

Comment: Looks like it. It's easy to mix up $[n]_q!$ and $(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^n)$ (which of course differ only by a factor of $(1-q)^n$): that's a mistake that I make all the time when writing these kind of generating functions.

Comment: @SamHopkins yes, exactly my thought...

Comment: Did you try contacting Richard Stanley directly? He is usually very responsive to this type of thing.

Comment: @TimothyChow I know he is active here on MO, so I figured he will see it here :) 
But I also put it here in case someone else gets stuck at the same spot, and then, have a place to find this post. But yes, I'll make sure to get it into the errata.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix this.

Comment: On second thought, just before Corollary 7.23.9 I define $[n]!_q=(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^n)$, and similarly for $[n]!_t$. My notation for $[n]!_q/(1-q)^n$ is **$(n)!$** (in boldface---MO displays all math in boldface, which doesn't work so well for my notation).

Comment: @RichardStanley Ah, I see! My mistake for not looking up the convention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(In order that this question appears as answered I'm converting Richard's comment into an answer.)

The (somewhat nonstandard) convention in the text, stated just before the corollary, is that $[n]!_q = (1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^n)$. For the quantity $[n]!_q/(1-q)^n$, the notation $\mathbf{(n)!}$ is used instead.